# ModuleNotFoundError sklearn.preprocessing, Pickle

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, spyder, anaconda3

I have trouble with the execution of my code in Pycharm and Spyder. Beside updating all the modules with `pip update --all`.

In my console, I have this message

```
[scaler, model_power, model_alpha, model_d632] = pickle.load(open("simulator/sag.sav", 'rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.preprocessing.data'
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code or my modules' version.

Any help?

Comment: please provide the code; likely an import error

Comment: I imported these packages like :
'import xarray as xr'
'import numpy as np'
'import pickle'
'from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression'

But I have the module error.

Comment: from sklearn import preprocessing . And, there is not 'data' attribute on this module

Comment: Please read the guidelines for asking questions better.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade scikit-learn:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

And try first to dump. For example:

```
filename = "simulator/sag.sav"
pickle.dump(filename, open(filename, 'wb'))
model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
print("model loaded")
```